# WebComponents: Do nested projected nodes belong to the shadow root of a parent component

Tags: javascript, html, web-component

Suppose you have the following template of the `my-app` root web-component:

```
<a-comp>
    <b-comp>
        <d-comp></d-comp>
    </b-comp>
</a-comp>
```

My question is whether both `b-comp` and `d-comp` belong to the `my-app` component in DOM and `b-comp` considered projected into `a-comp` component, while `d-comp` considered projected into `b-comp`? **I'm looking for some specification that defines that.**

I've tried to test it with native mode in Angular and got the following:

[image]

which seems to prove my assumption visually. I also tested with selectors:

```
const shadow = document.querySelector('my-app').shadowRoot
shadow.querySelector('a-comp'); // <a-comp>​…​</a-comp>​
shadow.querySelector('b-comp'); // <b-comp>​…​</b-comp>​
shadow.querySelector('d-comp'); // <d-comp>​…​</d-comp>​
```

which proves that projected web components belong to the `my-app` component.

Answer (score 0):

Before Shadow DOM developers used to use `<iframe>` to do, basically, what Shadow DOM does now.

Each `<iframe>` created a new `document`. So if you were three `<iframe>s` deep then you had 4 documents.

Shadow DOM creates something akin to a new document.

On a browser that supports Shadow DOM, calling the function `document.body.getRootNode()` returns `document`.

But calling `el.getRootNode()` on an element within a Shadow Root will return that shadow root. And each element inside another shadow root down will return that level's shadow root.

This is the document that allows the CSS to exist outside the scope of the parent document. The shadow root acts alot like its own document and prevents things from the outside from stepping on things inside the shadow root.

for `<a-comp>` to have `<b-comp>` as a child inside its shadow root, then it either had to be put there through a slot, or it was created by `<a-comp>` and placed inside its shadow root.

But is `<b-comp>` is not inside of the shadow root of `<a-comp>` then they are both in the same shadow root. In your example:

```
<a-comp>
  <b-comp>
    <d-comp></d-comp>
  </b-comp>
</a-comp>
```

All of these components are within the same shadow root.